# In ASP.NET MVC how to make sure a variable dont get any value from client

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In a model of ASP.NET MVC application, how can we make sure that a particular parameter (i.e. a property) doesnot accept any value from the client.plese note, though we can simply not show any control   like textbox or combobox for it , but a hacker kind of a person can send the values from http interceptor like webscrape etc.

so is there data annotation or so for it.

Comment: What do you mean? What kind of parameter are you talking about? What should set this parameter?

Comment: Simply you may declare that property as get type.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with an ActionFilter that clears form parameter before it's processed by controller.

sth like this:

```
public sealed class ClearValueActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{    
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.Remove([attribute name]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you controller action method you can use `Bind` attribute to exclude a property you want:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude="Property)]Model model)
{
 ....
}
```